# ethereum eth_sendTransaction via PHP curl

Tags: transactions, ethereum, json-rpc

I am trying to send ethereum transaction using PHP curl

There are number of other calls which are successful but this one...

**Code snippet:**

```
$url = "http://127.0.0.1:9999";

        $data = array(
                "jsonrpc" => "2.0",
                "method" => "eth_sendTransaction",
                "params" => array("from" => $f, "to" => $t, "gas" => $gv, "gasPrice" => $gp, "value" => $value),
                "id" => "1"
        );

        $json_encoded_data = json_encode($data);

        var_dump($json_encoded_data);

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_encoded_data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json_encoded_data))
        );

        $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
        curl_close($ch);

        $parsed = $result->result;

        return $parsed;
```

**JSON encoded data:**

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_sendTransaction","params":{"from":"0x35fa3c7edd23b23bd714fd075d243097e14ed937", "to":"0xdab9a603ed3f1cf7b2b89f1cb1b57145e4828796","gas":"0x15f90","gasPrice":"0x430e23400","value":"0x9b6e64a8ec60000"},"id":"1"}
```

Transactions are not getting submitted and there is no error apart form **Notice** in the logs `PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$result in...`

**Command line:**

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_sendTransaction","params":[{"from":"0x35fa3c7edd23b23bd714fd075d243097e14ed937","to":"0xdab9a603ed3f1cf7b2b89f1cb1b57145e4828796","gas":"0x15f90","gasPrice":"0x430e23400","value":"0x9b6e64a8ec60000"}],"id":"1"}' http://localhost:9999
```

Above works perfectly...

Can one please point out what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `params` field is missing a wrapping array. Try this:

```
"params" => array(array("from" => ...
```